# Automating daily task

Tags: python, web-scraping

We receive daily a zip file contain hundreds of html file which summarizes the operations details on our working locations.

So , I want to automate the process by downloading the zip to specified location then scrape through all the html and extract certain information and append that information to csv . The process should be repeated daily with no supervision.

I don’t need you guys to code it for me. I am only interested on how you guys going to approach it and solve it . So the workflow is what i am looking for to see how professional programers do it .

I will be using python. And it is my first project.

Comment: you can use Selenium to download your files, os to move it to the correct location, BeautifulSOap to scrape the html files and finde your inforations, maybe with some regex, if you are a python beginner you can search on the web more info about his modules and packages, remember to find something to unzip your file and to create your csv :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) for running tasks with [Cloudwatch event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) to schedule tasks and [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for storage.

Disclaimer: I am not professional but I am running several apps from converting video to scrape web, ... and they work very well!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to complicate a lot and if you are working on windows, you can create a task in the Task Scheduler that executes your script every day at X hour. Another approach can be using a daemon that verify the folder every X time to process the files, or a simple `while True` with a `time.sleep(hr)` at the end of the loop.

Comment: If you are using Linux, you can use `crontab` to manage task schedules.

Comment: Did OP mention Windows?